# Extension of the definition of $ \exists ! x, P(x)$

Tags: logic, set-theory, propositional-calculus

In propositional logic the statement "there exists a unique $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds" is generally written

$$ \exists ! x,  P(x) \tag{1} $$

and defined as

$$(\exists x, P(x)) \wedge (\forall x, \forall x', P(x) \wedge P(x') \implies x=x') \tag{2}$$

I am trying to extend this to two (and more) objects, that is, I would like to formally define the statement "there exists unique $x$ and $y$ such that $P(x,y)$ holds":

$$\exists !x, \exists !y, P(x,y) \tag{3}$$

I haven't been able to find anything on this in the literature or on the web. It seems natural to define (3) as

$$(\exists x, \exists y, P(x,y)) \wedge (\forall x, \forall x', \forall y, \forall y', P(x,y) \wedge P(x',y') \implies (x=x') \wedge (y=y')) \tag{4}$$

However, what if I chose to rewrite (3) as

$$\exists ! x, Q(x) \tag{5}$$

where

$$Q(x): \exists !y, P(x,y) \tag{6}$$

?

Then using the initial definition (2) in (5) and (6) in turn does not seem to be equivalent to (4). Namely, rewriting (5) gives:

$$ \color{blue}{(\exists x, Q(x)) \wedge (\forall x, \forall x', Q(x) \wedge Q(x') \implies x=x')} \tag{5'}$$

Rewriting (6), we see $Q(x)$ is equivalent to

$$\color{green}{(\exists y, P(x,y)) \wedge (\forall y, \forall y', P(x,y) \wedge P(x,y') \implies y=y')} \tag{6'} $$

Putting everything together (substituting (6') into (5') we must have (I apologize for the revolting expression):

$$ \color{blue}{(\exists x,} \color{green}{[(\exists y, P(x,y)) \wedge (\forall y, \forall y', P(x,y) \wedge P(x,y') \implies y=y')]} \color{blue}{\wedge (\forall x, \forall x',} 
\color{green}{[(\exists y, P(x,y)) \wedge (\forall y, \forall y', P(x,y) \wedge P(x,y') \implies y=y')]} \color{blue}{\wedge} \color{green}{[(\exists y, P(x',y)) \wedge (\forall y, \forall y', P(x',y) \wedge P(x',y') \implies y=y')]} \color{blue}{\implies x=x')} \tag{5'+6'}$$

It is difficult to see how this could possibly be reduced to the natural extension (4).

Thus my questions are:

- What is the proper/accepted definition of (3)?
- Was it legitimate to write (3) as (5)?
- If yes, how does one show (5'+6') $\iff$ (4) ?

Comment: Treating $\exists!x$ as a quantifier, the natural interpretation of (3) would be (5) and (6). By contrast, (4) says there exists exactly one *pair* $(x,y)$ such that $P(x,y)$, which is not equivalent.

Comment: No propositional but predicate logic.

Answer (score 1):

The expansion of "($\exists ! x)\,P(x)$" says: there is at least one $x$ such that $P(x)$, and there is at most one $x$ such that $P(x)$. By analogy, you might define "there is exactly one pair $x,y$ such that $Q(x,y)$" as follows -- pretty much your (4):

$$
(\exists !_{pair} x, y)\,Q(x,y) := (\exists x)(\exists y)\,(Q(x,y) \land  (\forall u)(\forall v)(Q(u,v)\rightarrow u = x \land v = y)
)
$$
There's no requirement that $x\neq y$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula $$\exists !x, \exists !y, P(x,y) \tag{3}$$ says that there is exactly one $x$ for which there is exactly one $y$ such that $P(x,y)$

Note that that would be true in a world with two objects $a$ and $b$ and where $P(a,a)$, $P(a,b)$, and $P(b,a)$ are true: there is indeed one and only one object (namely $b$) that stands in the $P$ relationship to exactly one object.

So this is not at all the same as there being exactly one pair of objects standing in the $P$ relationship.

Your (5) and (6) follow the former (correct) interpretation of (3), while your (4) is trying to capture the existence of a unique pair. Clearly they are not equivalent.

So, if you want to formalize there being a unique pair, you should not use (3), but extend your notation and maybe do something like $$\exists !(x,y), P(x,y)$$ which you can then interpret as your (4)